# How to calculate velocity of air through a pipe?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, fluid-dynamics, velocity, flow

I was wondering if there is any equation that helps to calculate air velocity through a pipe? I cannot find anything although I did find that velocity of air (not in a pipe) can be found by:[image]

Is there anyway, however, to use this equation to find velocity of air in a pipe?

Comment: duplicate of [this](http://engineering.stackexchange.com/q/8004/3100) question on Engineering...

Comment: that is dealing with water i am dealing with air

Comment: the equations are the same for air and water, i.e. newtonian fluids in general

Comment: no because air's velocity will depend on its temperature

Comment: The density of air is dependent on the temperature, the same with the density of water. Are you dealing with nonisothermal and compressible flows? If not then the equations are exactly the same except you use the density and viscosity of air instead of water.

Comment: yes sorry that is my fault I did not mentions it. I am dealing with compressible flow (compressible gas).

Comment: With compressible I meant that the flow is near sonic, if the velocity is low enough you can consider the gas as incompressible and you can use the equations with little loss in accuracy even for air. Of course this is difficult to say since you want to calculate the velocity so after using the equation you need to check that indeed the velocity is subsonic.